# Powershell and enums defined in C++/CLI assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, powershell, c++-cli

I have an assembly written in C++/CLI that contains a heap of enum defined like the following, one after the other in a single header file.

```
namespace Fix
{
    public enum class Side
    {
        SideBuy = '1',
        SideSell = '2'
    };
}
```

I can reference these types in other C# projects, and in IronPython, I can reflect the assembly and see them all with no trouble at all. I've also been using them in Powershell for many months with no issues - until now. I reference them like this:

```
[Fix.Side]::SideBuy
```

I have just moved from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 and now some of the enums I have defined like this are invisible to Powershell. I don't see any difference in the declarations and I can reflect the types with no problem.

This is a .NET 4.0 assembly and I have configured Powershell to run with the 4.0 runtime. I did that with the following registry changes.

```
reg add hklm\software\microsoft\.netframework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add hklm\software\wow6432node\microsoft\.netframework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Has anyone had issues like this?

Comment: how did you configure powershell to work with 4.0? did you verify with $psversiontable?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me. My steps:

I build a C++/CLI .NET 4.0 assembly with a single source file (except stdafx.*):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace Fix 
{ 
    public enum class Side 
    { 
        SideBuy = '1', 
        SideSell = '2' 
    }; 
}
```

Then I create and invoke this test script:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\...\TryEnum40.dll"
[Fix.Side]::SideBuy
```

It works: the enum value is printed as expected.

How do I configure my PowerShell to work with .NET 4.0? I do not use any registry tricks. I create the XML file “powershell.exe.config” in the PS home directory (or in a home directory of an application that implements a PowerShell host (e.g. MyApp.exe.config), I tried such a scenario, too).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

x64 machine: the file also needs to be copied to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

P.S. If this still does not help, could you please provide the exact error message that you get?

Comment: No joy, thanks for the config file option though, the registry hack was a pain because it affected other software.

Comment: The simple case you've demonstrated also works for me, in the real situation I have many enums defined in the header file. Powershell simply says it cannot find the type, I can also get it to fail on different types by reordering the declarations. It's very strange. I've also had a user report the same problem with a class type.